# How to move search icon to the left side of header and menu on the right

Tags: css, wordpress

Tried the following css code that didn't work.  The website is https://islandxuntitled.com/

```
#search-icon {
position: relative;
left: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your HTML, you have a `<ul>` list with id `main-nav`, where the `<li>` items of that list contain menu items and in particular, the search button (with search icon) to be shifted.

There are a few ways to achieve left-most placement of the search button/icon - one simple option would be to add the following CSS:

```
ul#main-nav {
    /* 
    Create space at left side of menu nav for search button 
    */
    padding-left:2rem;
    position:relative;
}

ul#main-nav #nav-search {
    /* 
    Position search button at absolute left position relative to parent menu nav 
    */
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    width:2rem;
}
```

Comment: will that also put it on the left side of the mobile as well?

Comment: @webdeveloper111132 yes it will for tablet size screens however it seems the website hides the search button for smartphone sized screens

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
ul#main-nav{
 display:flex; 
 align-items:center;
}

ul#main-nav li#menu-item-4154{
order:1;
}

ul#main-nav li#nav-search{
order:0;
}

ul#main-nav li#hb-cart-count{
order:2;
}
```

Also, if you want to have search icon on far left then:

```
ul#main-nav{
 display:flex; 
 align-items:center;
 width:100%;
 justify-content:flex-end;
}

ul#main-nav li#menu-item-4154{
order:1;
}

ul#main-nav li#nav-search{
order:0;
margin-right:auto!important;
}

ul#main-nav li#hb-cart-count{
order:2;
}
```